# ASN.1 REAL - BER decoding

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, asn.1

I was given the task on the subject ASN.1 decoding formats. I passed something storing structure tag is REAL, and I have to disassemble it and put in the type double. Problem is that very little information on the Internet. The number that I need to convert decimal form.

Here's an example:

```
first-man NUMBER ::= 
{  
    numb 11.987
}
```

The result is a number:

```
30098007 0231312E 393837
```

Immediately a lot of questions, the standard BER states:

```
A BER encoded "tag" is made up of several bit fields:

---------------------------------
| 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
---------------------------------
|Class  |P/C| Tag Number        |
---------------------------------
```

If I know that I will come exactly the type REAL, then why do I parse this structure, because it only selects the tag. Well, we got the number **30098007 0231312E 393837**. So what? What part of me can drop to decode back **11.987** , because I know that it is a floating point number. And in general, whether there is any structure in Microsoft for this coding?

Or if I know that my number in decimal form. I just used to decode the string? Such as the number 5.65 in the form of NR2 = "+5.65"? Just like that?

Comment: If each two hexadecimal numbers in "31　31　2E 39　38　37" are recognized as ASCII character code, they becomes "1 1 . 9 8 7".

Comment: @Fumu 7 - then that means **02** 31312E 393837?

Comment: No, "31312E 393837" can be interpreted as "11.987".  "02" is not a printable code.  Ascii code &h02 is  a control code STX (State of TeXt). Let take a look in ASCII code table in http://www.asciitable.com/, you may be able to find "31" in Hexadecimal (Hx) means character "1", "2E" means character ".", and so on.

Comment: Now is `numb` defined?

Comment: @Fumu7 02 is the control byte that indicates that the number is in NR2 format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking the nested blocks:

```
30 09     -- SEQUENCE, of length 9
   80 07  -- [0], context-specific Tag 0 of length 7
      02 31 31 2E 39 38 37 -- ?? "11.987"
```

Context-specific means that its meaning is supposed to be known from the context. For instance, I haven't a clue what it means, because I don't have any context for it. As for that 02 byte -- it could be anything.

So this can't be decoded without further information. Where did it come from?

Comment: I just tried various examples on the website: http://asn1-playground.oss.com/. That is, if I'm sure I have a REAL and the code was obtained from the number of decimal form, when decoding I can safely discard it: 02 30098007?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't described your task properly yet. In particular, you have to tell us (i) the definition of `numb`; (ii) the meaning of context-specific tag `[0]`.

Comment: Passed to the function encoded by ASN.1 real number in decimal form, return this number in the format double.

Comment: There is no ASN.1 type `DOUBLE`.

Comment: Of Course, the function to convert ASN.1 REAL in C ++ double.

Comment: OK, now I get it. So please answer my questions (i) and (ii).

Comment: (i) String "300980070231312E393837" And I know that it is encoded REAL to 10 form, which can be verified before.

Comment: (ii) I do not know. This is just an example, there were so.

Comment: Well then, whatever you do will just be shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll ask the head accurately.

Answer (score 2):

See [ITU-T X.690](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-200811-I/en), §8.5, which describes the contents encoding for the REAL type. In practice, the REAL value is only rarely used.

Tony has provided a good breakdown of the encoding, which is a tag-length-value triad, but the encoding `02 31 31 2E 39 38 37` could use a little clarification. To understand the `02` prefix, we need to consult §8.5.6:

> Bit 8 of the first contents octet shall be set as follows:
>
> a) if bit 8 = 1, then the binary encoding specified in 8.5.7 applies;
>
> b) if bit 8 = 0 and bit 7 = 0, then the decimal encoding specified in 8.5.8 applies;
>
> c) if bit 8 = 0 and bit 7 = 1, then either a "SpecialRealValue" (see ITU-T Rec. X.680 | ISO/IEC 8824-1) or the value minus zero is encoded as in 8.5.9).

`0x02` is `0b00000010`, so (b) applies here. 8.5.8 describes three possible forms, further specified in ISO 6093. Since that's an ISO standard, you won't find one freely available. These formats are, I believe, all ASCII character strings.